# If given limit is equal to $e^3$, then calculate $\ln (ab^3)$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $$\lim_{x\to 0} \bigg[ \tan \bigg(\frac{4x^2}{a} \bigg)+\sec \bigg(\frac{9x}{b} \bigg) \bigg]^{\frac{ab}{x^2}}=e^3$$

Then find $\ln (ab^3)$

Using certain manipulation, I got
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \bigg[ \tan \bigg(\frac{4x^2}{a} \bigg)+\sec \bigg(\frac{9x}{b} \bigg)-1 \bigg]{\frac{ab}{x^2}}=3$$

Then I wrote it as
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \bigg[ \tan \bigg(\frac{4x^2}{a} \bigg) \bigg]{\frac{ab}{x^2}}+\lim_{x\to 0} \bigg[ \sec \bigg(\frac{9x}{b} \bigg)-1 \bigg]{\frac{ab}{x^2}}=3 $$

Is this step correct, because in the end I got $4b+\frac{81a}{4b}=3$ through which I am not able to calculate $\ln (ab^3)$. Answer should be an integer.

Comment: Should be $4b+81a/(2b)$.